# Is there a `git` command commits all of add/modify/remove at once?

Tags: git, command, addition

As I know, I have to use

```
git add . 
git commit -m "Test."
```

to add files.

And for update and delete,

git commit -a -m "Test."

However second command does not handle file addition.
Is there a command which does all of these at once?

Comment: Do you really want to add files to your source control that indiscriminately?  I would think this would frequently result in a bunch of temporary files (like swp files) from being checked in by accident.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for care. However I'll separate all source code into a single directory (including its subdirectories) from other files. And I want to commit the directory at once. I want to handle a bunch of source code as a package :)

Comment: just use a bash script if you really want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Though, if you can guarantee that all un-ignored, un-versioned files want to be versioned, `git add .` is a doozy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add and commit, you can create a shell script that does that.

`git add .; git commit -a`

This will open up the editor specified in your `.gitconfig` and you can enter the commit message.

You can even parameterize the path you want to add:

`git add $1; git commit -a`

Comment: You probably don't want to commit if the `git add` command failed. These two commands should be `git add . && git commit -a` and `git add $1 && git commit -a` respectively.